# Adding Logo in Header of Word document using python-docx

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I want a logo file to be attached everytime in the word document, when I run the code,

Ideally the code should look like :

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
logo = open('logo.eps', 'r')                  #the logo path that is to be attached
document.add_heading('Underground Heating Oil Tank Search Report', 0) #simple heading that will come bellow the logo in the header.
document.save('report for xyz.docx')              #saving the file
```

is this possible in the python-docx or should i try some other library to do this? if possible please tell me how,

Comment: A "header" in Word is a block of text in the top-margin area of each page, generally appearing the same on every page. A "heading" is often a "section heading" and is a title paragraph, generally bold and bigger than the body text, used to introduce a new section. Which do you want?

Answer (score 5):

with the following code, you can create a table with two columns the first element is the logo, the second element is the text part of the header

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches, Pt
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
document = Document()
header = document.sections[0].header
htable=header.add_table(1, 2, Inches(6))
htab_cells=htable.rows[0].cells
ht0=htab_cells[0].add_paragraph()
kh=ht0.add_run()
kh.add_picture('logo.png', width=Inches(1))
ht1=htab_cells[1].add_paragraph('put your header text here')
ht1.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
document.save('yourdoc.docx')
```

Answer (score 5):

A simpler way to include logo and a header with some style (Heading 2 Char here):

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches, Pt

doc = Document()

header = doc.sections[0].header
paragraph = header.paragraphs[0]

logo_run = paragraph.add_run()
logo_run.add_picture("logo.png", width=Inches(1))

text_run = paragraph.add_run()
text_run.text = '\t' + "My Awesome Header" # For center align of text
text_run.style = "Heading 2 Char"
```