# Python: issue using WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT with photo

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

When using the titular command with an image after using "add_run", the image is not right aligned. I was attempting to recreate something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53475659/adding-logo-in-header-of-word-document-using-python-docx) but swapping the picture and text section. Unsure if this can be achieved with the library.

```
from docx import Document
from docx2pdf import convert
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
from docx.shared import Inches, RGBColor, Pt

header = doc1.sections[0].header
htable = header.add_table(1,2,Inches(9))
htab_cells = htable.rows[0].cells
ht0=htab_cells[1].add_paragraph()
kh=ht0.add_run()
kh.add_picture(holder_logo,width=Inches(.75))
kh.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
header1=htab_cells[0].add_paragraph().add_run("Notice to Zero Dollar Change\nDATA CENTER")
header1.font.size = Pt(16)
header1.font.name = 'AvantGarde LT Book'
header1.font.color.rgb = RGBColor.from_string("0266BB")
```

Comment: Have you tried using tabs for header content alignment as described in the documentation here: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/hdrftr.html#adding-zoned-header-content?

Comment: @scanny , I read the docs on it but I wasn't sure how to apply that to a photo, or if that's a possibility. I tried adding tabs to the right of the text in the header but that didn't affect the photo at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to swap the line

```
kh.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
```

to

```
ht0.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
```

Unsure as to why but that did the trick now the logo is oriented properly.

Comment: `ht0` is a `Paragraph` object where `kh` is a `_Run` object. Paragraph alignment only applies to paragraphs. You might want to use variable names like `paragraph = cell.add_paragraph()` so you can keep track of what type of object you're operating on. I find that very helpful.